# Timeseries correlation between multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series, multiple-columns

I am trying to establish the relation between Temperature  and the usage of devices marked as code (19-26).
This is how the sample data looks like:

How can I statistically prove the relation between uses of different devices (19-26) and -temperature over the given period of time. Date ranges from 2020-04-24 to 2021-05-11.
Device Usase data contains hourly usage of the specified devices (code).

```
    time    19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  Timezone    Precipitation (mm)  Snow depth (cm) Temperature (degC)
0   2020-04-24 00:00:00 12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  UTC 0.0 0.0 6.2
1   2020-04-24 01:00:00 12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  UTC 0.0 0.0 6.2
2   2020-04-24 02:00:00 12  12  12  14  12  13  12  13  UTC 0.0 0.0 5.1
3   2020-04-24 03:00:00 13  14  15  12  18  20  23  20  UTC 0.0 0.0 4.6
4   2020-04-24 04:00:00 24  15  23  24  19  25  30  28  UTC 0.0 0.0 4.7
```

```
merged_df['Temperature (degC)'].max() -->27.9
```

```
merged_df['Temperature (degC)'].min() -->-21.2
```

I tried plotting this, but getting an image that has two overlapped image.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Melt the DataFrame to reshape it into a long format
melted_df = merged_df.melt(id_vars=['time', 'Temperature (degC)'], 
                           value_vars=[str(i) for i in range(19, 27)], 
                           var_name='Device', 
                           value_name='Device Usage')

# Set up the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Plot the data
sns.lineplot(data=melted_df, x='time', y='Temperature (degC)', color='blue', label='Temperature (degC)')
sns.lineplot(data=melted_df, x='time', y='Device Usage', hue='Device', palette='muted', legend='full')

# Adding labels and title
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Temperature and Device Usage Over Time')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')  # Position the legend

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Gupta. Have you tried using seaborn's pairplot method? https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html